# Windows 10 Photos Slideshow Feature

Tags: windows-10, photos, slideshow

The default picture app in Windows 10 and it's slick, I would like to use it in place of Windows Photo Viewer like I did in 7/8 but it seems to be missing one important feature.  When I simply double click on an image to open it it will only show that image.  In Windows Photo Viewer I could manually change between pictures in the same directory with the arrow keys.

So, the question:  **Is there a way to turn on a similar feature in Photos?**

Comment: Just tested on my PC and the arrow keys work by default. Are you using left and right or up and down?

Comment: Left and right.  Come to think of it I think they might have worked before but it definitely was not working last night.  I will try again later, I do not have that laptop with me currently

Answer (score 0):

Using the arrow keys I could view prev/next images (for local files), but not when previewing images from a network share or NAS. I'm not sure if a fix is available for the latter.